# How to put multiple copy of a content in a page easily?

Tags: multido

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multido,fullpage}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0cm,top=0.7cm,bottom=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\centering
\multido{}{2}
{DABBAS packeging dates of AL DHAFRA brand  are found\\01515611989, 4\textsuperscript{th} year, CSE, DU\\Room - 1406, Ex-1, SH Hall\\\vspace{1.4cm}}
\end{document}
```

[image]
This way I can put two copies of the content in a page. If I change the number to 3 then there will be create another page. I want to such a solution that allow me to change the multido count and fit the result with one page instead of creating new page.

In my WE I use a specific font. I have not much attention on font. If I can't use specific font for such solution I am ready to consider.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Maybe have a look at `pgfpages`? You could create a small page and place it n times on a bigger one.

Comment: Can you create a MWE that does not rely on special characters and fonts? More people might be able to help you.

Comment: @samcarter I change the character, use English only. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can just make the original text a bit smaller (for example with a `scalebox` and a `parbox`) to fit more copies on one page?